# Why FormData object empty

Tags: javascript

When I run below code , I always get an empty FormData , is it because of the form too complex ? How should I change the code ?

It seems if I only use tags like form , input , label to construct the form , the FormData object will not get to be empty . Maybe I can manually construct a line and send it via XMLHttpRequest , but have a better way ?

Any help would be appreciate , thank you for your time .

html:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="inquiry" name="inquiry" method="post" role="form"><!--action="processData.php"-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="name">Your name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" maxlength="100">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="email">Your email address</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" maxlength="100">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" maxlength="100">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="message">Your message</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="message" maxlength="5000"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button id="post-message" type="submit">
                <span>Send Message</span>
            </button>
        </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

js:

```
'use strict';
var Contact = function() {
  var sendData = function() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest() ;
    var url = "/php/processData.php";
    var inquiryForm = document.forms.namedItem("inquiry");
    var FD = new FormData(inquiryForm);
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url , true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var returnData = xmlhttp.responseText ;
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.send(FD);

    for (var [key, value] of FD.entries()) {
      console.log(key, value);
    }
  };

  var windowLoadHandler = function() {
    window.addEventListener("load",function(){
      var inquiryForm = document.getElementById("inquiry");
      inquiryForm.addEventListener("submit",function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        sendData();
      });
    });
  };

  return {
    init : function(){
      windowLoadHandler();
    }
  };
}();
```

Comment: Why `sendData` is inside anothe function

Comment: Note that `namedItem` is not cross-browser, you should be using just `this` in the submit handler to catch the form instead. And as noted above, the `Contact` function is never executed, and the `sendData` function is inside it.

Comment: Is `Contact.init()` actually invoked before the page has finished loading?

Comment: @adeneo yes , below is in the html , I forget to post here:<script> $(document).ready(function(){ Main.init(); Contact.init(); }); </script> .and I try to use var inquiryForm = document.getElementById("inquiry"); to replace namedItem , I think not working either ..

Comment: So you're using jQuery? Why are you making it this difficult ?

Comment: @Mikael Lennholm , I think so , cos I also add some console.log functions to know where the code stops which are deleted here .

Comment: @adeneo some old code is jQuery , but i want js to do this here ? you mean i should just use Form.submit() to make things less difficult ?

Comment: Oh my. This is just really obvious, but none of your form elements have a `name`. If you want them to be sent, they'll need a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to add names to all the form elements, otherwise they won't be sent with the form.

Here's the code with some changes to make it work

```js
'use strict';
var Contact = (function() {
  var sendData = function(form) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "/php/processData.php";
    var FD = new FormData(form);

    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var returnData = xmlhttp.responseText; // note, async, can't be used outside this function 
      }
    }

    xmlhttp.send(FD);
    console.log()
    for (var pair of FD.entries()) {
      console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
    }
  }

  var windowLoadHandler = function() {
    var inquiryForm = document.getElementById("inquiry");

    inquiryForm.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      sendData(this);
    });
  }

  return {
    init: function() {
      windowLoadHandler();
    }
  };
})();

$(document).ready(function() {
  Contact.init();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="inquiry" name="inquiry" method="post" role="form">
  <!--action="processData.php"-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="fullname">Your name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname" name="fullname" maxlength="100">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="email">Your email address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" maxlength="100" name="email">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" maxlength="100" name="subject">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <label for="message">Your message</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" maxlength="5000" name="message"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <button id="post-message" type="submit">
                <span>Send Message</span>
            </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

By the way you're calling `Contact.init()` you probably wanted an IIFE.
Note that `name` is always a poor name for a variable, and even a worse name/ID for an element, as `window.name` already exists.

See how the form is just passed from the event handler, to the function.